# Accessing calendar entries on the iPhone/iPod touch

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

is it possible to access calendar entries on the iPhone/iPod touch, i.e. reading, creating, changing, deleting appointments?

I searched the iPhone SDK documentation but didn't find anything. Perhaps I missed something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently this functionality is not supported by the SDK. If you need this, please consider filing a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com) with Apple.

Comment: Yes, EventKit is now part of the API, and gives you access to the calendar in iOS 4.0.